# Get function value from a Remote Powershell call

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I invoke a Powershell script(.ps1) remotely which calls a function from a 3rd party assembly (Rebex SFTP component). This function returns an integer value. This remote call is done from C# code.

I want to cast the result of that call to int for further processing in the C# code.

How can this be done most effeciently ?

Here is some code:

Code snippet of the RemoteInvocationManager (custom class with Powershell Remoting, just the important parts):

```
using (Pipeline pipeline = remoteRunspace.CreatePipeline(scriptText))
{
Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

       foreach (PSObject obj in results)
       {
         stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
       }
}
```

Code snippet of the call to the RemoveInocationManager:

```
string command = @"& c:\temp\sftp\mytransfer.ps1";
string result = RemoteInvocationManager.RunScript(command);
```

Code snippet of the Powershell script (.ps1 file):

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files (x86)\Rebex\SFTP for .NET 2.0 Trial\bin\Rebex.Net.Sftp.dll")
$sftp = New-Object Rebex.Net.Sftp
$sftp.Connect("127.0.0.1")
$SshPrivateKey = New-Object Rebex.Net.SshPrivateKey("c:\temp\sftp\keys\private\myprivatekey.ppk", "myuser")
$sftp.Login("myuser", $SshPrivateKey)
$sftp.PutFile("c:\temp\sftp\input\file1.txt", "/output/fileout.txt")
$sftp.Disconnect()
```

Comment: Show some code that you have tried ( relevant snippets)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want:

```
int output;
bool isSuccess = int.TryParse(result, out output);
if(isSuccess){
//use outout
}
```

Update:

To suppress out put for things you don't need use `[void]` or pipe to `Out-Null`

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files (x86)\Rebex\SFTP for .NET 2.0 Trial\bin\Rebex.Net.Sftp.dll")
```

or

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files (x86)\Rebex\SFTP for .NET 2.0 Trial\bin\Rebex.Net.Sftp.dll") | Out-Null
```

Comment: I get two rows returned now, one with the output of the LoadFrom call and the 2nd returns '12' (which is the size of the file transfered). Is there a way the suppress the output of the 1st row so that I can call your supplied C# tryparse code ?